# How to translate "speak one's piece"?

Tags: traducción, modismos

The title says it all, how do you say "speak one's piece"[1] in Spanish?

[1] Speak your piece means "state your opinion or view".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a debate if the correct phrase is "Speak one's piece" or "Speak one's peace". I have no intentions to go into details here, so I'm going to assume they are equivalent, or otherwise as explained [here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=115).

From [Modismos Ingleses Para Hispanos/English Idioms For Spanish Speakers (2007)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764137522), it's actually [quite straight forward](http://books.google.com.mx/books?id=LRVXSi97SOEC&pg=PA406&lpg=PA406&dq=speak%20one%27s%20piece%20spanish&source=bl&ots=WkKchHdBFH&sig=DP4sn-xa26-AiuWurfmIQJglQq4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1iEeU6XrBKW62gWHwYHYBw&ved=0CHQQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=speak%20one%27s%20piece%20spanish&f=false):

> Decir todo lo que se tiene que decir.

The example the book gives is:

> He spoke his piece. Dijo todo lo que quería decir.

It references someone's need to say something. I agree with the book, it would just translate to "decir lo que se tiene que decir" or "decir lo que se quiere decir".

Comment: ['Speak your piece' and 'hold your peace'](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=115)

Comment: Just read the Merriam-Webster link. I guess it's one of those things I've never written before...thanks for the insight. Interestingly, Google gives 36 M results for the incorrect version, and only 27 M results for the correct version. Looks like a lot of people are confused!

Comment: @neizan I'd recommend to use Google's ngram viewer instead. See [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speak+my+piece%2Cspeak+my+peace&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeak%20my%20piece%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspeak%20my%20peace%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to make a translation without any context or even a full sentence.

Let's imagine the sentence in English was:

> He'd planned to **speak his piece** at the next meeting.

then a translation into Spanish could be:

> Había planeado **hablar sin reservas** en la próxima reunión.